# FabricJs: parts of grouped objects are being cropped when canvas is reloaded from db

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am having an issue where after reloading a group object, it is being cropped and parts of the object are not appearing.

So here is the object after grouping multiple objects together...
[image]

After I save the data and reload it, the same object loads in like this...
[image]

As I wrote this code quite some time ago, and it is quite complicated, I am not sure exactly what code to share at this point. I am just looking for a general direction on where this issue might be occurring.

Basically, this is the json data I am saving to the DB...

```
var json = JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON(['id', 'groupId', 'componentType', 'diametre', 'objectHeight', 'resizable', 'locked', 'view', 'info', 'pathName','color', 'shape', 'opacity', 'system', 'svgUid', 'format', 'filters', 'tags']));
```

And this is how I am loading it...

```
canvas.loadFromDatalessJSON( this.props.canvasJson, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), function(o, object)
```

Any assistance as to where to look for the problem would be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share the json that you load from database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the problem.

I needed to add 'objectCaching' as a property to the canvas.toDatalessJSON() so that when the canvas is reloaded, the object has objectCaching set to false.

```
var json = JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON(['id', 'groupId', 'componentType', 'diametre', 'objectHeight', 'resizable', 'locked', 'view', 'info', 'pathName','color', 'shape', 'opacity', 'system', 'svgUid', 'format', 'filters', 'tags', 'objectCaching']));
```